# Accessing variables from a vector that stores objects

Tags: c++

How would I be able to access x or y variables from the octagons vector after storing the object.

I know how I'd access x and y from the lots_of_coordinates vector as this would just be `lots_of_coordinates[0].x` but I would want to do the same but from the octagons vector.

```
public:
    int x, y;
};

class OctagonBase {
public:
    vector<Coordinate>coordinates;
    Coordinate point1;
};

class Octagon : public OctagonBase {

public:
    void Coordinates() {
        point1.x = 30;
        point1.y = 40;
        coordinates.push_back(point1);
        cout << coordinates[0].x;
    }


};

int main() {

    vector<Octagon*>octagons;

    Octagon o;
    o.Coordinates();
    octagons.push_back(o);

    //how do I access x from octagons?  
}
```

edit:

I've got it to work using `octagons[0].point1.x;` and also changing `vector<Octagon*>octagons` to `vector<Octagon>octagons`. However is there a way to do it with `vector<Octagon*>octagons`.

Also if I change int x and y to private, would it still work if I add the appropriate setter and getter functions?

Comment: Change `vector<Octagon*>octagons;` to `vector<Octagon> octagons;` and `octagons.push_back(o);` will work.

Comment: it works when changing it to `octagons[0].point1.x;` but is there a way I can do the same but keeping it as  `vector<Octagon*>octagons;`

Comment: ```
vector<Octagon*> octagons; 
octagons.push_back( new Octagon ); 
octagons[0]->point1.x = 42;
```

Comment: @robthebloke using that code almost works - could you please explain why we have to use `(new Octagon)` ? Using `cout << octagons[0]->point1.x` this prints 0 rather than 30?

Comment: You have to use `new` because you want  to store a pointer to a  `Octagon`. With that said I don't recommend `Octagon*` because of the manual memory management (what you new you are responsible to delete). You may want to use a smart pointer instead if you really want a pointer.

Comment: It's printing '0' because the Coordinates method that sets the value to 30, has not been called. Call it, and the value will change. I agree with what @drescherjm says though...

Comment: @robthebloke sorry if I sound silly but I thought its called at `o.Coordinates();` or should I be doing something else as should be a pointer?

Comment: vector<Octagon*> octagons; octagons.push_back( new Octagon ); octagons[0]->Coordinates();

Comment: @robthebloke thanks, that seems to work. If you like you can write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int main() {

    vector<Octagon> octagons;

    Octagon o;
    o.setCoordinates();
    octagons.push_back(o);

    //how do I access x from octagons?  

    // either via an integer index
    for(size_t i = 0; n < octagons.size(); ++i)
    {
      for(size_t j = 0; j < octagons[i].coordinates.size(); ++j)
      {
        std::cout << octagons[i].coordinates[j].x << '\n';
      }
    }

    // or a range based for loop
    for(auto& octagon : octagons)
    {
      for(auto& coord : octagon.coordinates)
      {
        std::cout << coord.x << '\n';
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Generally speaking though, you usually want to hide direct access to internal data where possible *(so that the public interface describes actions)*. It usually makes the class easier to work with.

This is NOT something I'd recommend, but if you want to manually manage the memory yourself, you can do:

```cpp
vector<Octagon*> octagons; 
Octagon* ptr = new Octagon;
octagons.push_back(ptr); 
octagons[0]->Coordinates();
```

Just make sure to remember to free them again.

```cpp
for(auto ptr : octagons)
  delete ptr;
```

Imho, you'd be better off with `std::vector<Octagon>` though, since the memory would be contiguous, and therefore be somewhat faster to process.